# How do I solve for $x$ when the equation is as follows?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

I have tried to attack this problem in numerous ways, but I'm stumped. Initially I though I could extend the denominators to "fit them all" but it's a very tedious process. Surely there is a more effective approach! Could you point me in the right direction?

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-2} &= \frac{1}{x-3} - \frac{1}{x-4}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

Simplify each side by combining the fractions

$$\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-4}$$
$$\frac{(x-2)-(x-1)}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{(x-4)-(x-3)}{(x-3)(x-4)}$$
$$\frac{-1}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{-1}{(x-3)(x-4)}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This helped me a ton, thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)